# ember - Failing to save a new model

Tags: ember.js, model

I have a very simple author model with one field, name. I have a form in my authors/new template that calls the action save when it is submitted.

```
<form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
  {{input value=model.name placeholder="Name"}}<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">

</form>
```

In my route for authors/new I define the model to create a record for author, then define the action save to save this model.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.createRecord('author');
    },
    actions: {
        save() {
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});
```

However when I click the save button, I get the following error in my console.
`Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).save is not a function`. Can anyone help me out as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this.get ('model') returns function model defined in route...one possible solutions would be move your save function to controller it will work.

Comment: Get model from controller instead of from route. To get controller use var cont =this.controllerFor('authors.new'); cont.get('model').save ();

Comment: You can get the model in your route by using [modelFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and cleanest would be to pass the model to your save function:

`<form {{action "save" on="submit" model}}>`

`save(model) {
    model.save();
}`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `modelFor` only for nested routes.

As you only implement the `model` hook in your route, ember will apply all the other hooks with default implementation.

It sets whatever is returned from the model hook as `model` on your `controller`.

So what you can do here is:

```
   let newAuthor = this.get('controller.model');
   newAuthor.save().then(() => { return console.log('it saved!') });
```